# How to convert negative values to positive in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples like that:

```
tuple_list =  [(1, -1), (3, 0), (3, -2), (-1, -3)]
```

I need to convert all elements in positive values like that:

```
tuple_list1 =  [(1, 1), (3, 0), (3, 2), (1, 3)]
```

And finally I want to sum each element inside a tuple:

```
tuple_list2 =  [(2), (3), (5), (4)]
```

Could someone hellp me please?

Comment: 3 + 0 is not equal to 2 (your second resulting item)

Comment: (2) is not a tuple

Comment: `[(sum(map(abs, el)),) for el in tuple_list]` or `[sum(map(abs, el)) for el in tuple_list]`

Comment: @martineau That's a nice post.  It's a shame mods have locked it and may delete it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Assuming you're referring to the accepted answer to the linked question — being locked doesn't necessarily mean it's likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map `abs` to each element in your tuples to get them to be positive. Note that `(2)` is not a tuple, `(2,)` is a tuple.

```py
tuple_list =  [(1, -1), (3, 0), (3, -2), (-1, -3)]
[(sum(map(abs, el)),) for el in tuple_list]
```

Output: `[(2,), (3,), (5,), (4,)]`

```py
tuple_list =  [(1, -1), (3, 0), (3, -2), (-1, -3)]
[sum(map(abs, el)) for el in tuple_list]
```

Output: `[2, 3, 5, 4]`

Comment: @Buckeye14Guythank you for replying. I am gotting as output : Out[437]: 
[(<map at 0x257fe820f60>,),
 (<map at 0x257fe820898>,),
 (<map at 0x257fe820d68>,),
 (<map at 0x257fe820cc0>,),
 (<map at 0x257fe820da0>,)] Would you know which could be the problem?

Comment: Did you do `[map(abs, el) for el in tuple_list]`? If so then just do `[tuple(map(abs, el)) for el in tuple_list]`. `map` creates a map object which is what you are seeing. to make it a list or tuple you have to use the `list` or `tuple` construct. There are other ways but don't worry about them

Comment: No I think you did `[(map(abs, el),) ...]` or something similar. If you used the code I typed exactly you will not have any problems. `[tuple(map(abs, el)) for el in tuple_list]`. The `(element,)` way of constructing tuples does not make use of iterables

Comment: Now it worked. I did [tuple(map(abs, el)) for el in tuple_list], and after I used a for loop to do the sum of elements: lst = []
for x, y in displacement:
    a = x + y
    lst.append(a)
And I got the good result! Thank you very much to take your time to kindly help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the list comprehension to iterate over the values to convert them into positive values and applying sum over the list of positive values and then atlast converting the result into a tuple.

```
tuple_list =  [(1, -1), (3, 0), (3, -2), (-1, -3)]
result = [(sum([abs(a) for a in x]),) for x in tuple_list]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(2,), (3,), (5,), (4,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
tuple_list =  [(1, -1), (3, 0), (3, -2), (-1, -3)]
tuple_list2 = [(sum(map(abs, sl)),) for sl in tuple_list]
```

**Output** :

```
[(2,), (3,), (5,), (4,)]
```

`tuple_list2 = [sum(map(abs, sl)) for sl in tuple_list]` should produce `[2, 3, 5, 4]` output.